# Bing Video Detail API - 404 not found

Tags: bing-api, azure-cognitive-services

I'm implementing BING search API's, all works fine.
But the API ()[given here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn760795(v=bsynd.50).aspx) to get Video's detail and its related videos throws 404 Error.https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/videos/details

Anyone has any idea how to get it work?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me. Did you pass the id of the video in the url param? As mentioned in the documentation, when you use the /videos/details endpoint, you need to use the id parameter to identify the video you want to get insights for.

If you still see the issue, send me a sample url with the search parameters you're using, and I'll investigate.